# Create a new column showing that one of a previous group is contaminated in r

Tags: r

I have a list of different groups , I want to create new column that indicates that at least one person in that specific group id has been met that condition .
ex

| Group ID | Dead |
| --- | --- |
| 12 | 0 |
| 12 | 1 |
| 12 | 0 |
| 130 | 0 |
| 130 | 0 |
| 144 | 1 |
| 144 | 1 |
| 144 | 0 |

and want to make a new chart like this

| Group_ID | Dead | Affected |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 0 | 1 |
| 12 | 1 | 1 |
| 12 | 0 | 1 |
| 130 | 0 | 0 |
| 130 | 0 | 0 |
| 144 | 1 | 1 |
| 144 | 1 | 1 |
| 144 | 0 | 1 |

this goes on longer with varying group sizes

the data comes from a larger set which im piping through in which i tried

```
    test1 <- LargeSet%>% 
 group_by(Group_ID)%>%
  mutate(affected= case_when((Dead>0~1), (Dead<1~0)))
```

i keep getting matching dead and affected rows instead

Answer (score 0):

You can test the sum of "dead" variable for each id with a sapply function, as follows.
If the patient has a sum>=1 then the affected value would be 1 ; 0 otherwise.

```
#1- Dataset creation
df=data.frame(id=c(12,12,12,130,130,144,144,144),dead=c(0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0))

#2- Creating and filling the affected variable
df$affected=sapply(df$id,function(x) ifelse(sum(subset(df,id==x)$dead)>=1,1,0))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative using `any`. After grouping by `Group_ID`, `any` will return TRUE or FALSE for a group if at least one of the rows has `Dead` that's not zero (in this case). The `+` in front of it will convert the logical result to either 1 or 0.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(Group_ID) %>%
  mutate(Affected = +any(Dead))
```

You can also use `+any(Dead == 1)` to be more specific to values in the `Dead` column.

**Output**

```
  Group_ID  Dead Affected
     <int> <int>    <int>
1       12     0        1
2       12     1        1
3       12     0        1
4      130     0        0
5      130     0        0
6      144     1        1
7      144     1        1
8      144     0        1
```